# Co-prime solutions of Linear Congruences

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Suppose I have an linear congruence

$axt \equiv x (\text{mod } m)$  where $gcd(ax, m) = x$.

Then this has $x$ solutions of the form

$t_0 + k(m/x)$  for $k \in \{0, 1, ..., x-1\}$, where $t_0 \equiv a^{-1}(\text{mod }m/x)$.

I think at least one of these solutions is co-prime to $m$, but I am unable to prove that. Does anyone have any idea on how to go about proving that, or is there a paper that contains such a proof (or counter example).

Thanks,

Mike